# Help Identifying a rune, or binding

Tags: germanic-languages

The german band Rammstein used this to portray the Letter "R" in their logo from 1993, but cannot find a matching rune or a mix of them what would produce this symbol, my guess it's a stylized Old Germanic "R" binded with a hyphen to indicate the number 6

Also resembles a portion of the "Helm of awe"

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it's a variant on ᛉ (**algiz*), which is conventionally transcribed as *z*, *r₂*, or *ʀ*. The phoneme it represented is reconstructed as **z* in Proto-Germanic and eventually merged with *r* in later Norse, but it's not clear what exactly it was in between those two times, so different scholars transcribe it differently. It's entirely possible non-linguists flipping through a book on runic orthography would see it listed as capital *R*, and use it as such.

Comment: Yes this is probably it with Yr rune ᛦ turned upside down. 
Also was suggested by a friend that maybe it wasn't a rune at all and just a representation of a gear shift

Comment: I think they could afford to consult a dozrnt linguists if necessary. I don't see where OP's idea with the 6 came from, but I too thought numbers.